# want to show updated status value in another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

i want to watch when a mutation called and updated a status. i make a component to show database table count when api called.

this is my store i wrote

```
const state = {
    opportunity: ""
}

const getters = {
    countOpportunity: state => state.opportunity
}

const actions = {
    // count opportunity
    async totalOpportunity({ commit }) {
        const response = await axios.get(count_opportunity)
        commit("setOpportunity", response.data)
    },
}

const mutations = {
    setOpportunity: (state, value) => (state.opportunity = value)
}
```

i want to show this getter value when this mutation called in another component name Opportunity.vue file. 
i showed database count values in file name Dashboard.vue

i wrote it like this.

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["countOpportunity"])
  },
  watch: {},
  mounted() {
    //do something after mounting vue instance
    this.$store.watch(() => {
      this.$store.getters.countOpportunity;
    });
  },
  created() {
    this.totalOpportunity();
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["totalOpportunity"])
  }
```

and showed my view like this.

```
<div class="inner">
 <h3>{{ countOpportunity }}</h3>
 <p>Opportunities</p>
</div>
```

when api called and count increase shows my mutations. but my view value not updated (countOpportunity). any one can help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here (most likely) is that the value of `response.data` is an object or an array. You've initially defined opportunity as `''` which is not an observable object or array. You have 2 choices:

Redefine it as an empty object or array, depending on the response:

```
opportunity: [] // or {}
```

Otherwise, use `Vue.set()` to apply reactivity when changing it:

```
(Vue.set(state, 'opportunity', value))
```

Comment: i tried with set opportunity as property. but same as my problem. how can i use vue set